# Using the CodeIgniter tables library I am having an issue. It keeps printing an extra row with two columns in it

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here's the code in order of Model, Controller, Then View

// MODEL

```
function get_all_events()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('events');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query;
    }
}
```

// CONTROLLER

```
    // get the data from the database
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $gettabledata = $this->admin_model->get_all_events();

    // create the table template
    $tbltmpl = array (
        'table_open'          => '<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">',
        'heading_row_start'   => '<tr>',
        'heading_row_end'     => '</tr>',
        'heading_cell_start'  => '<th>',
        'heading_cell_end'    => '</th>',
        'row_start'           => '<tr>',
        'row_end'             => '</tr>',
        'cell_start'          => '<td>',
        'cell_end'            => '</td>',
        'row_alt_start'       => '<tr>',
        'row_alt_end'         => '</tr>',
        'cell_alt_start'      => '<td>',
        'cell_alt_end'        => '</td>',
        'table_close'         => '</table>'
    );

    // set the template
    $this->table->set_template($tbltmpl);

    // create the table headings
    $tableheadings = array (
        'ID','NAME','DATE','IMAGE','ADDED','MODIFIED','&nbsp;'
    );

    // set the table headings
    $this->table->set_heading($tableheadings);

    // create the table rows
    foreach($gettabledata->result() as $row)
    {
        $tablerow[] = $this->table->add_row(
            $row->event_id,
            $row->event_name,
            $row->event_date,
            $row->event_image,
            $row->event_added,
            $row->event_modified,
            'edit | delete'
        );
    }

    // generate the table and put it into a variable
    $data['table'] = $this->table->generate($tablerow);
```

// VIEW

```
<div class="block_content">

    <?php echo $table ?>

</div>
```

So, it'll print the table just fine, but it then also prints an extra row at the bottom. The extra row has two columns in it.

Comment: are they empty columns? and do a `print_r($query)` so you can see what is being returned

Comment: yes, they are empty and this is what's printed:         Array ( [0] => [1] => )

Comment: Update, I just realized something. At the time I only had 2 records in the DB, so I added two more. Now my extra row has 4 columns in it. So each records seems to be generating extra columns.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this library, but just a thought, it says in the userguide that you don't have to include all the options in the template. Have you tried not specifying the row_alt and cell_alt options in the template? Could they generate the unwanted rows?

Comment: i have removed them, and they weren't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

I didn't realize that since I was adding rows, I didn't need to include the $tablerow variable in the actually generate method. This was causing the extra row with columns.